# Having issue in my LeagueGothic-Regular font. Font Installed but not reflection in website

Tags: fonts

Having issue in my  LeagueGothic-Regular font. Font Installed but not reflection in website. I have downloaded from this link http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/tag/alternate%20gothic%20no.1

```
Here is my html code:
<div class="my">Hi I am here</div>

Here is my css
@font-face
{
font-family: "LeagueGothic-Regular";
src: url('fonts/LeagueGothic-Regular.otf');
}



.my{
font-family:"LeagueGothic-Regular";
font-size:24px;
}
```

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to see whether the font file is actually getting loaded under that path

Comment: No it is not loading I have checked lot

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path? `domain.com/fonts/.....`

Comment: yes done that..  you try please it will take 10m only

Comment: Do you have this live somewhere?